# XCode4 Organizer - App fails validation due to CFBundleVersion error

Tags: xcode, validation, version

When submitting a new version of our app to the Apple app store, I am receiving the dreaded "This bundle is invalid.   The key CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously uploaded version."

I'm puzzled by this, since I've updated this app many (>6) times previously.   The current version app details from iTunes Connect shows that the bundle version previously uploaded is "5780".

The new version has a bundle version of 6001, however, this results in the aforementioned validation error.

I have tried various permutations of the bundle string (5781, 10000, 1.6.1, etc.) all to no avail.   This is on Xcode 4.3.2 running on Lion 10.7.3   Again, this far from the first update and the same process has worked previously - the only difference that I am aware of is that the previous update was done with Xcode 4.3.1.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase not only build number - CFBundleVersion (5780->5781) but also marketing version - CFBundleShortVersionString (1.6.0 -> 1.6.1)

Comment: Thanks.   I tried this without success, unfortunately.  The previous value of CFBundleVersionShort was '1.5.5', so I had thought that '1.6.0' would have addressed it.   I did try '1.6.6' at one point as well, knowing how Apple splits the values apart but this had no positive effect either unfortunately.

Comment: It sounds weird, but iTunes Connect sometimes forces you to make version number higher than highest version number among *all* your apps

Comment: Interesting - good to know!   This client has only a single app in the app store, however, so I'm not sure that's the problem in this case.

Comment: I've tried it again, this time with both CFBundleVersion at 7000 (far above the 5780 of the previous version) and CFBundleShortVersionString at "1.6.7000".   No joy with this combo.

I'm really starting to think it's either on Apple's end or the message Organizer is displaying isn't accurate.

Comment: Try to use Application loader (you can download it from iTunes Connect). If it will not help, I have only one suggestion - change major version number, i.e. to 2.0

Comment: Thanks - I tried it, but application loader also failed.   

I found something interesting - although my source Info.plist file has the bundle version in it, the Info.plist file as copied to the archive is missing it entirely!   I suspect this is the cause of the problem, so now I need to understand why Xcode isn't writing CFBundleVersion to the output plist file...

Comment: Ok, here's the followup for anyone who comes across this. I cleaned the project, shut everything down, rebooted, and had no success.   A day later, however, I was able to successfully validate and submit the same archive which had failed the day before.   No idea what the actual problem was at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this error when trying to update an app from 1.09 to 1.5. The solution for us appeared to be changing 1.5 to 1.50, but that wouldn't have helped with your numbering scheme. Perhaps it was an issue of needing to wait, and that number worked simply because more time had elapsed. The app then validated and submitted without issue.